# How do I check if an int is a decimal?

Tags: java, int

I need help with something that can help me check if an int is a decimal.
Something like:

```
if(variable == decimal){ //assuming the variable was entered by a user
    System.out.println("This number is a decimal.");
} else 
    System.out.println("This number is an integer.");
}
```

Comment: a int is never a decimal.  I think you mean ....is an number is a decimal

Comment: @ÉricRoberge I'd say, an int is always a decimal

Comment: While all `int` can be written as a decimal it is expected to be a 32-bit signed integer i.e. binary rather than decimal, though the JVM could store it in any form. The most common variations are big and little endian.

Comment: In contrast not all `double` can be written as a decimal e.g. NaN, and +/i Infinity.

Comment: this question makes 0.00 sense

Answer (score 1):

If your "variable" value is a double then :

```
return Math.floor(variable) == variable;
```

Will return true if "variable" is an Integer.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that my variable is an int

Comment: @A.Wang So even if your user enter "23.441" for instance. Your "variable" object will get the "23" value :p